# Ascending/Descinding filter on array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array that I need to create which I do by doing an forEach() on 2 levels to get the data. I tried to filter it the basic way but with no succes, is it cause of the **ø** caracter ? :

```
const ascending: any= values.sort((a,b) =>  (a > b ? 1 : -1));
```

Here's my code and the array :

**Array I'm trying to filter**

[image]

**Full array that I forEach on :**

[image]

**Filter methode : ( dataDynParts being the second picture )**

```
  filterDrop() {
    const newArr = [];
    const secondArr = [];
    this.dataDynParts.forEach((item) => {
      item.items.forEach((val) => {
        val.diam.forEach((rez, index) => {
          console.log(index)
          if (newArr.findIndex(i => i === rez) === -1) {
            if (index === 0) {
            newArr.push(rez);
            }}
          if (secondArr.findIndex(i => i === rez) === -1) {
            if (index === 1) {
              secondArr.push(rez);
            }
          }
        });
      });
    });
    console.log(secondArr);
    this.dataDiam1 = newArr;
    this.dataDiam2 = secondArr;
    this.filteredWithDiam = this.dataDynParts;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem to work correctly - more or less. You're trying to sort diameters, which in reality are numbers. But you're sorting strings, so i.e. "100" will come before "25" (since 1 is before 2).

To have it work properly, you'll need to parse your values to numbers and then compare them. Let's assume that they all have initial character of **ø**.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
values.sort((a: string, b: string) => {
    // Remove the first character and replace . with , to prepare for parsing
    const aVal = a.substr(1).replace('.', ',');
    const bVal = b.substr(1).replace('.', ',');

    // Parse to numbers
    const aNum = parseFloat(aVal, 10);
    const bNum = parseFloat(bVal, 10);

    // Compare values
    return aNum - bNum;
});
```

Below is non-typescript version for the stack overflow snippet testing:

```js
var values = ['ø63', 'ø22'];
var values2 = ['ø50', 'ø25', 'ø40', 'ø16,5', 'ø100', 'ø165'];

var sort = (values) => values.sort((a, b) => {
    // Remove the first character and replace . with , to prepare for parsing
    const aVal = a.substr(1).replace('.', ',');
    const bVal = b.substr(1).replace('.', ',');
    
    // Parse to numbers
    const aNum = parseFloat(aVal, 10);
    const bNum = parseFloat(bVal, 10);
    
    // Compare values
    return aNum - bNum;
});

console.log(sort(values));
console.log(sort(values2));
```

Comment: Oh that's why I couldn't get it to work, it does now. Thank you for the really detailed explanation, really appreciate it and it works really well!